# How to increase the IIS response chunk size

Tags: iis, iis-6, httpmodule

We are migrating our sharepoint 2003 to espace. Though users are informed about the migration, some users are still using the old links. This could be because they have saved the old urls in Favourite sites and trying the same.  So we thought of developing ISAPI dll, with which we can catch the 404 File Not found or "Site not in content DB"  error and redirect the user to correct site.

So I developed one ISAPI dll in Visual C++.  To redirect the user I am modifying the location to new url and set the HTTP status to **HTTP 302 Redirect**. But one challenge I am facing here is, IIS sends response in chunks and "site not in content DB" error text comes as part of the second chunk. By the time first chunk with header info, including status and location will be passed and I will not be able to modify further.

**Is there any way I can increase the size of the IIS response chunks?**

Comment: Some more Info - The response now come in 2 different chunks - First chunk - HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Date: Mon, 14 Jan 2013 06:05:27 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 6.0.2.6568
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET    --------------------------------------------------------------------                                     Second Chunk - Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1252

<HTML><BODY>The Web site that is referenced here is not in the configuration database.</BODY></HTML>  --------- But i want these the second chunk also to be part of first chunk.

Answer (score 0):

I tried -

`Stsadm.exe ?o setproperty ?pn large?file?chunk?size ?pv <size in bytes>` to increase the chunk size.

It works!!